# SOSL query to return the count of all standard and custom objects from an org

Tags: sosl

Is there a simple SOSL query that one can use to determine the number of objects in an org? A bonus would be to determine what type of object it is (custom, standard, packaged) etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible using SOSL or SOQl. But you can easily do this using Global Describe

```
  Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> GlobalDescribe = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
  system.debug('----------------No Of Objects-----'+GlobalDescribe.size() );

  for(Schema.SObjectType objTyp : GlobalDescribe .Values()){
      Schema.DescribeSObjectResult ObjDesc = Obj.getDescribe();
      if(ObjDesc.isCustom())
         system.debug('--Custom Object or Custom setting---');
      else
         system.debug('--Standard Object---');

  }
```